# CUDA: how to represent efficiently 2-D arrays on the GPU

Tags: cuda

I need to process a 2-D array with dimensions K x N on the GPU, where K is a small number (3, 4, or 5) and N has a value of millions to 100s of millions.
The processing will be done for one column of K elements at a time, such that each column will be processed by a separate invocation of a kernel.
What is the most efficient way to represent the K x N array on the GPU:

1) in a 1-D array, placing the K elements of a column in consecutive locations, so that each thread will process elements K*thread_id, K*thread_id + 1, ..., K*thread_id + K - 1

2) as K separate 1-D arrays, where each array stores 1 row of the original array;

3) something else

Thank you!

Comment: 2D Arrays are usually stored as strided 1D memory, like you desccribed in the first point.

Answer (score 2):

The option 2 is better for your case.

The data layout of your option 2 can be seen as the structure of arrays (SoA), while the option 1 is the array of structures (AoS).

Generally the SoA is better than the AoS for GPU programming. There are a lot of discussion on this topic showing why SoA performs better.

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/introductiontothrust.pdf

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9780123884268/chapter-6dot-efficiently-using-gpu-memory/st0045_b9780123884268000069

Since each thread accesses the K elements one by one, AoS layout in your option 1 leads to strided memory access issure and can hurt the performance, which is discussed as follows.

https://developer.nvidia.com/content/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-cc-kernels

Although this issue could be relaxed by a large enough L2 cache in your case, avoiding AoS is a more robust way to get higher performance.

Comment: How about for cases when K can be greater than 5, and can vary widely from column to column? That is, each column can have a different number of useful elements. How will you represent the array in that case?

Comment: @user1760748 In that case, each of your threads probably have to run a different code path to access the data. This code pattern is not suitable for GPU, no matter the data is colum-major or row-major.